# What control could I use to represent deep hierarchy structure?

Tags: asp.net, hierarchy, radgrid

I'm going to build a hierarchy structure. Each layer contains about 12 columns and in total I'll have 7 layers of hierarchy.

I have used [RadGrid Hierarchy nested table][1] features on some of the pages which had 1-2 nested tables and it works fine, however, on this page because mainly there are 7 layers of hierarchy I can't use RadGrid Nested Tables as the 7th Nested table gets opened in the middle of the page in that case!

What other control could I use to represent such structure?

Any idea? e.g. Master/Detail, Multiview, etc?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master / Detail View:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/selectedvalue/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the [Treeview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) Control.

Comment: like I said, 12 columns have to be shown on each Grid. TreeView only shows 1 data at each row. Also it would be again a horizontal hierarchy like RadGrid; same issue will appear with TreeView.

Comment: It would be a pain to manage, but you could also use nested Repeater Controls.